# Python resampling and filtering question

Tags: filters, python, decimation

**Intro**

Hi I'm looking for someone with some experience to walk me through some questions I have regarding resampling (downsampling) in Python.  Here is my problem:
I have accelerometer data that comes in irregularly at 50Hz.  Sometimes I get 50 samples a second, sometimes 1 every 3 seconds.  I also get velocity data that comes in at 1Hz also fairly irregularly.  My question is, how best to filter and align the data?

**Problem**

I have been using the pd.resample("1s").mean()  and pd.resample("1s").last() methods to downsample/decimate my data.  When using the .last() method I have been using a low pass filter with a cutoff of 0.5Hz prior to decimation.  As far as I can tell, the .mean() acts as it's own low pass filter, but I'm not sure if this is correct as there should be a difference between using a moving average filter and then resampling vs resampling into 1 second bins and then taking the mean.  I have seen in a lot of online dicussion people simple use pd.resample().mean() and that seems wrong to me.

Anyways, anyone with any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: Are you able to time stamp the data; so even if irregular you know where in time each sample occurs.

Comment: Are you saying that the data comes to *you* at irregular intervals, or that it's *actually sampled* at irregular intervals?

Comment: The data is timestamped so I know when each time sample occurs.  It's actually sampled at irregular intervals.

Comment: Anyone have any input or resources that would be helpful?